# Passing an array of objects to a spinner and specify field name for the text it shows?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way (like .net, flex, etc... do) to pass a spinner an array of objects and the field that will be used to show the values in the spinner?. It is a bit of a pain to retrieve entities from a database, convert the part you want to an adapter to strings, etc... and pass it to the spinner. A much better solution would be to pass the container directry and tell the spinner, use this field to show up as the spinner item caption.

Comment: First show us what have you tried!

Comment: You have to code your own adapter.

Comment: @Vipul Shah: Haven't tried nothing yet. Just wanted to know if it is factible to do it. Jeje Doudou: I have done this in the past. Just wanted to know if there's a better/easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but you can somehow bind your spinner to an array of Objects (in the example below "specialties").

```
        ArrayAdapter<Specialty> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Specialty>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, specialities);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpecialtySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And in the Specialty object I override my toString() method to show what I want my spinner to show.